# ¿Es posible hacer los bordes redondeados en un ListTile en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ui

¿Es posible hacer los bordes redondeados en un ListTile? he intentado con clipRRect y con shape del ListTile y no he logrado hacerlo. Gracias

[image: Ejemplo]

```
child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              title: Text(
                user.fromFullName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainBlue,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que usas?

Comment: Puse lo máximo que me dejó stackoverflow porque no me deja poner todo, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

si se puede con estas propiedades `shape`

````
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
) ```

Deberian verse algo asi(imagen de ejemplo[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1])


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubJDP.png
````

Comment: Gracias! pero probé de poner shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),), y no me da resultado. no lo cambia.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre el ejemplo que pusiste en tu pregunta, si es posible, te dejo el código, solo necesitas usar el `tileColor` para darle el color al tile, el `shape` ya no es necesario porque al ponerle color no considera el shape, así que por eso toca usar `ClipRRect`.

```dart
ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        child: ListTile(
          tileColor: Colors.blue,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
          title: Text(
            'Username',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.red,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Prueba y me avisas, te recomiendo mi canal para contenido avanzado de Flutter :) https://youtube.com/diegoveloper

Si no te funciona agrega que versión de Flutter usas,  `flutter doctor`

Comment: Gracias Diego ya lo pruebo! te sigo hace años y veo tus videos!

Comment: dale, ya actualicé mi respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Con la ayuda de los maestros pude solucionarlo, tal como dijo Fernando Herrera y diegoveloper ClipRRrect si esta cortando el ListTile (con un color de fondo se ve claro) sin embargo dejaba las esquinas blancas, eso lo solucione envolviendo el ClipRRrect en un Container y dándole el color que quiero. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

```
child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              child: ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                tileColor: Colors.blue,
                title: Text(
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Creo que si es posible, envuelve el ListTile en un ClipRRect y prueba, ojo que son 2 R's (ClipRRect)

Comment: Hola Profe! sigo tu curso en Udemy! he probado envolver en ClipRRect y no obtengo resultado. sigue igual, esto viendo con la propiedad shape del ListTile pero ya habia probado y no me dió resultado.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que es demasiado importante realizar respuestas en base a [answer] ya cuentas con reputación para realizar comentarios, saludos.